# Long query times for simple MySQL SELECT with JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM song AS s
     JOIN user AS u
            ON(u.user_id = s.user_id)
WHERE s.is_active = 1 AND s.public = 1
```

The s.active and s.public are index as well as u.user_id and s.user_id.

song table row count 310k

user table row count 22k

Is there a way to optimize this? We're getting 1 second query times on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have a compound "covering" index on song: `(user_id, is_active, public)`. Here, we've named the index `covering_index`:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.user_id)
FROM song s FORCE INDEX (covering_index)
JOIN user u
ON u.user_id = s.user_id
  WHERE s.is_active = 1 AND s.public = 1
```

Here, we're ensuring that the JOIN is done with the covering index instead of the primary key, so that the covering index can be used for the WHERE clause as well.

I also changed `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(s.user_id)`. Though MySQL should be smart enough to pick the column from the index, I explicitly named the column just in case.

Ensure that you have enough memory configured on the server so that all of your indexes can stay in memory.

If you're still having issues, please post the results of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: We're not looking for a single user, we're looking for a total song count for songs that successfully relate to a user. Users can get deleted, but songs can't.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't index all three of those because we're joining and the user_id is from a different table. Also, we have plenty of memory. http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/covering-indexes/ The covering index must include all columns found in the SELECT list, the JOIN clause, and the WHERE clause. So I'm not sure if we can...

Comment: I've updated the query, still using the covering index, and telling MySQL to use that over the primary key to join.

Comment: 1.2771780 | Memory Before: 5.95 Mb | Memory After: 5.96 Mb | Memory Used: 1.55 kb | Rows: 1 | Slave: No
 
SELECT Count(u.user_id) FROM 
song s FORCE INDEX (user_id, is_active, public) 
     JOIN user AS u 
            ON (u.user_id = s.user_id) WHERE s.is_active = 1 AND s.public = 1
Id  Select Type  Table  Type  Possible Keys  Key  Key Len  Ref  Rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  s  ref  user_id,is_active,public  public  1  const  230830  Using where
1  SIMPLE  u  eq_ref  PRIMARY  PRIMARY  4  s.user_id  1  Using index

Comment: If you view source on the comment, it'll look better :) So far nothing has improved the query time. For the query above, the time actually increased .5 seconds.

Comment: The FORCE clause should include the name of the covering index, not the columns in the index.

Comment: Thanks. The covering index did the trick. Just as a note, putting in the force index wasn't necessary... removing it resulted in the same time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps write it as a stored procedure or view... You could also try selecting all the IDs first then running the count on the result... if you do it all as one query it may be faster. Generally optimisation is done by using nested selects or making the server do the work so in this context that is all I can think of.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM 
    (SELECT song.user_id FROM
        (SELECT * FROM song WHERE song.is_active = 1 AND song.public = 1) as t
    JOIN user AS u
        ON(t.user_id = u.user_id))
```

Also be sure you are using the correct kind of join.